# Browser exhibits strange behavior when using grid on Asp.net application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ultrawebgrid

I have developed an ASP.Net application which users use to enter their time sheets. The application is using a grid to display the days as columns and the entries as rows. Whenever the user enters values to the cells, signifying the hours spent for a particular project on a particular day, I have a JavaScript function which updates the column totals for the day. When the user focuses another row, the row total is also updated.

A strange behavior is exhibited when the number of rows of the grid exceeds 50 or so rows: when a new row is added, after the user populates the first cell, it takes up to 40 seconds for the total of the column to be updated, during which time the browser is waiting for the operation to finish. After control is returned to the browser, populating subsequent cells in the same row update the totals instantaneously. When a new row is added, the same behavior is exhibited.

Could someone please point me to where I should start troubleshooting this issue? Is this browser related (we are using IE 8), or should I look into the JavaScript code? I tried running this application using. Running the application using FF somewhow does not work, so I cannot test it that way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like your `ViewState` might be getting bloated after adding so many rows. If you're using the ViewState to store any page data, remove it and put it somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for your reply; I will check on that. I would think that since Viewstate is used by default in ASP.net, this is the case for my application as well, although I did not specifically set it like this. Do you mean however that it is used to store data other than the controls state? I am most certain that I don't use it for anything other than controls state. What is an alternative place to store that data? Also, would it not make sense that in case it is bloated all subsequent entries in cells would also take a long time?

Comment: Thinking about it Viewstate is not really being used in this example because there is no post back.

Answer (score 0):

The problem (for anyone who's interested) was with the getRow() method of Ig2010.3. I re-wired the logic of the page and it's now reading the content of the cell otherwise. It's ok now.